# Use SyntaxNet for chunking?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, syntaxnet

In an app I'm developing I need to know whether a string of words is a noun phrase, verb phrase, etc. I understand that NP and VP are neither dependencies nor POS. I also understand that to do this I probably need some sort of chunking tool but I couldn't find any open source ones.

In the output of SyntaxNet for the sentence "She really likes cute black dog":

```
likes VBZ ROOT
 +-- She PRP nsubj
 +-- really RB advmod
 +-- dog NN dobj
     +-- cute JJ amod
     +-- black JJ amor
```

I noticed that the NP "cute black dog" has been put in its own tree node:

```
 +-- dog NN dobj
     +-- cute JJ amod
     +-- black JJ amor
```

So I'm wondering if there is anyway I can use SyntaxNet as a chunker?

Comment: a *constituency* parser will tell you if you have an NP, VP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, there are accurate fast chunkers (like [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html)) out there, that I don't see why to use dependency parse trees to extract chunks.

Though you can have a look at [this google sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/language/syntax_triples/main.py)(this does not provides chunks but subject, object and verb) that might be useful for your application, and give you some clues to how define regexs to extract most of noun phrases.